# Phaser.js Physics group, draggable children

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a physics group, `this.photons`
I would like to be able to drag the children of the group separately, but still have it collide with other groups/group members

so far, `setDraggable` hasn't worked, and other questions I've seen so far either involve matter.js or a single sprite,

How would I do this, and preferably in arcade physics?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make the gameObject interactive, with the function `setInteractive`, if you pass a object with the property `draggable`, you don't need to call the function `setDragable` anymore.

Then you just need to implement the `pointerdown`, `drag` and `dragend` eventslisteners.
*The `pointerdown` is set on the gameObject and the `drag` and `dragend` on the InputPlugin.*

1. On `pointerdown` you simply need to save the current gameObject *(= photon)*.
2. On `drag` you just have to set the position of the currentselected gameObject, which was save on `pointerdown`.
3. On `dragend` you just need to clear the selected gameObject (and of good measure set the position once more).

**Here a small demo base on my last Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity: { y: 0 },
        }
    },
    scene: { create }
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Drag&Drop Demo')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillTriangle(0, 0, 10, 5, 0, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('img', 10, 10);
    
    this.photons = this.physics.add.group({
      key: "img",
      repeat: 2,
      setXY: { x: 50, y: 50, stepX: 32 },
    });

    this.photons.children.iterate(function (child) {
      child.body.bounce.set(1);
      child.setVelocity(Phaser.Math.Between(0, 100),30);
      let initialAngle = (new Phaser.Math.Vector2(child.body.velocity)).angle();
      child.setRotation(initialAngle);
      child.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
      child.body.onWorldBounds = true;
      
      child.setInteractive({ draggable: true });
      child.setScale(2);
      
      child.on('pointerdown',  () => {
        this.selectedPhoton = child;
      });
      
    }, this); // <-- don't forget to pass the context
    
    this.input.on('drag', pointer =>  {
        if(this.selectedPhoton){
          this.selectedPhoton.setPosition( pointer.x, pointer.y);
        }
    });
    
    this.input.on('dragend', pointer =>  {
        if(this.selectedPhoton){
            this.selectedPhoton.setPosition( pointer.x, pointer.y);
            this.selectedPhoton = null
        }
    })
    
    this.physics.world.on('worldbounds', (photon) => {
        let newAngle = (new Phaser.Math.Vector2(photon.velocity)).angle();
        photon.gameObject.setRotation(newAngle);
    });
    
    this.physics.add.collider(this.photons, this.photons, (p1, p2) => {
        let newAngle = (new Phaser.Math.Vector2(p1.body.velocity)).angle();
        p1.setRotation(newAngle);
        newAngle = (new Phaser.Math.Vector2(p2.body.velocity)).angle();
        p2.setRotation(newAngle);
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```